# iOS 5.1 and Default.png

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

I am developing an application using iOS 5.1 and I am experiencing some strange behavior with the default.png files.

I have added the following files to my application:

> Default.png - (iPhone)
>
> Default@2x.ping - (iPhone Retina)
>
> Default-Portrait~ipad.png - (iPad)
>
> Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png -(iPad Retina)

When the application starts it seems that it selects the correct Default.png image to use for each occasion. However in my AppDelegate I have a simple splash screen to make smoother the loading of the application and the transition to the app, doing something like:

```
UIImageView *splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,window.frame.size.width, window.frame.size.height)]; 
splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]; 
    
[window addSubview:splashView]; 
[window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
```

However the `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]` in turn does not select the correct file for each device, and I believe the problem is the `-Portrait` part of the filename.

So as a quick solution I did this:

```
if( ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ) {
    // Force the image used by ipads
    if( [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
       splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait@2x~ipad"];
    }
    else {
        splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait~ipad"];
    }
}
else
   splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"];
```

Is this how I should be doing this? Does this look funny to you?

Comment: Does this look funny to you?  that is funny

Comment: Try some NSLogging to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: @rokjarc How can you NSLog which file is being selected by the SDK when you do a simple `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]`?

Comment: I was talking about NSLoging in your if/else branches where you're the one defining filenames. I see now that i missunderstood your question. Will write an answer soon.

Answer (score 4):

For official information here take a look at: [App-Related Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html)

For Launch images use this format:

```
<basename><orientation_modifier><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png
```

It looks you would be better off using:

```
Default.png - (iPad)

Default@2x.png - (iPad Retina)

Default~iphone.png - (iPhone)

Default@2x~iphone.png -(iPhone Retina)
```

This should give you proper image even if using simply:

```
splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"];
```

Comment: `-[UIImage imageNamed:]` doesn't work -- as @mobius highlighted, the problem is with the orientation modifier. So something like Default~ipad.png will work but Default-Portrait~ipad.png doesn't work with `-[UIImage imageNamed:]` (even though at launch time the iPad does pick up the right image).

Answer (score 2):

Once my Universal app has finished loading, I display a copy of the launch screen in a `UIImageView` and then fade it out, to give a gentle transition between launching and the app being ready. Here's the code that I use in order to determine which image to use:

```
    // choose the correct launch image for orientation, device and scale
    NSMutableString *launchImageName = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Default"];
    BOOL isPad = ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad );
    if( isPad )
    {
        BOOL isLandscape = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]);
        NSString *imageOrientation = (isLandscape) ? @"Landscape" : @"Portrait";

        BOOL isRetina = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0);
        NSString *scaleString = (isRetina) ? @"@2x" : @"";

        // Default-Landscape~ipad.png
        // Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
        // Default-Portrait~ipad.png
        // Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
        launchImageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@%@~ipad.png", launchImageName, imageOrientation, scaleString ];

    } else {

        if( CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) > 480.f)
        {
            // Default-568h.png
            launchImageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@-568h.png", launchImageName];
        } else {
            // Default.png
            // Default@2x.png
            launchImageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", launchImageName];
        }
    }
    UIImage *launchImage = [UIImage imageNamed:launchImageName];
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html

```
App Launch (Default) Images
<basename><usage_specific_modifiers><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png

Providing Launch Images for Different Orientations
<basename><orientation_modifier><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png

Providing Launch Images for Custom URL Schemes
<basename>-<url_scheme><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png
```