# iOS @2x images UIImageView not being picked up

Tags: ios

EDIT: Looks like the 2x image was NOT actually 2x. I feel dumb :(

I have created @2x images for my images, but when I run the app in iOS simulator using retina the images are blurry. See attached screenshot.

[image: iOS 2x images not being picked up]

The url for the full image is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpk1k.png

Image of retina display is hardware device settings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyn2n.jpg

[image: ios Retina display]

Comment: It would help if you described how the images are loaded and how they are named.

Comment: When I run the iPhone simulator, it's the same size as the view on the storyboard. Are you sure that's not the iPad simulator? To specify iPad images use `~ipad` and `@2x~ipad` as the suffix.

Comment: The screenshot shows exactly how I named them in the sidebar where the images are. I am running in iPhone simulator.

Comment: Those dimensions don't seem right for an iPhone. You would also see the speaker for the ear. Check Hardware->Device in the simulator menu.

Comment: Try this naming convention for universal apps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10123362/653513 And Bennett Smith has a good point: check "target membership" for 'missing' images.

Comment: I checked target membership and cleaned the project and tried cleaning project and re-adding.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are referencing the image in a UIImageView that is part of a scene in a storyboard. When you pull down the list of images to choose from do you see both the normal and the @2x versions listed?  If you only see the normal version then the issue might be that the @2x image is not included in the target.

To make sure the image is in the target you should select the image in the project explorer (on the left side in Xcode) and then look in the utility panel (on the right side in Xcode) in the file inspector. Make sure the check box next to the target is checked in the "Target Membership" section.

Comment: I do see the @2x images when I try to add the images. I also checked the utility panel and the target was checked.